# How to enable scrolling in an ExtJS 4.1.1 TreePanel within a vbox layout?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bimargulies/yHuz2/

THis fiddle has two tree panels in a vertical column inside a panel with a vbox layout.

Adding autoScroll: true, or anything else I've tried, fails to enable scrolling inside the tree panels. Scrolling the overall containing left panel works.

Looking at the CSS, it seems as if the problem is that nothing in ExtJS is assigning a specific height to the panel, and so overflow styles don't have an effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When defining vbox layout, each sub item must have either `flex` or `height` config, so the layout can calculate the heights for these. Your code was missing these and adding them would enable scrolling.

In addition, in your case your layout definition should be:

```
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'stretch'
},
```

To tell the layout to stretch the tree nodes in the available space (the default align: `left` won't set the right margin of the nodes correctly), this will display the scroll bar where expected.

Here's the [modified version of your JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/yHuz2/36/) working as expected.

Comment: this is tantalizingly close. When I add flex: to both of the trees, expand/collapse stops working on the top one.

Comment: Well it seems to work on the JsFiddle I've submitted, so perhaps would be useful to see your recent code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bimargulies/ndPjF/4/. To cause the problem, I had to add collapsed: true to the top of the two trees.

Comment: @lzhaki though, in my real code, the collapse button misbehaves even if I don't start collapsed.

Comment: Although I'm not certain, my guess is that it is a bug in the framework - I've come across a few bugs with the collapse mechanism of panels; I would definitely say it is unbaked in 4.1.1; But in your case it shouldn't be such a big deal - have you tried collapsing the panel during onRender?

Comment: In the real code, I get the same troubles merely by making them collapsible. I think I'm shifting to an accordion to get out of this muddle. I nearly have that doing what I want.

Comment: +1 Your answer did not fix my issues but it did give me a much better understanding of ExtJs. Thanks a lot!